# react i18next hasLoadedNamespace: i18next was not initialized undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary, i18next

`Yarn start` causes intermittent errors.
No correction has been made to the code that is causing the error.

It is also common to save and recompile code from other files.
Once in a while you can render without any problems.

### Error

---

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaB0.png)

[Console alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ1k9.png)

**TypeError: t(...).map is not a function**

*Please check the image.

I made a map of the json file that i18next uses to translate.

`i18next: hasLoadedNamespace: i18next was not initialized undefined`
,

`key "about" for languages "en" won't get resolved as namespace "header" was not yet loaded This means something IS WRONG in your setup. You access the t function before i18next.init / i18next.loadNamespace / i18next.changeLanguage was done. Wait for the callback or Promise to resolve before accessing it!!!` is printed from the console with the error mentioned earlier.

### Package.json

---

```
{
  "name": "homepage",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/react-i18next": "^8.1.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

### Dir

---

```
root
|-public
|     |-locales
|          |-productWS
|                 |-en.json
|                 |-ko.json
|-src
|     |-components
|     |     |-MwsCard.tsx
|     |-systems
|     |     |-ProductWs.ts
|     |-i18n.ts
```

### en.json

---

```
{
    "miniTitle":"ABC",
    "title":"ABCDEFG",
    "text": "abcdefg",
    "version":[
        {
            "name": "1",
            "sensor": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
            "src":"/img/1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "sensor": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
            "src":"/img/2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

### ProductWs.tsx

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { MwsCard } from '../../components';
import { Wrap, Container, TitleH5, TitleH2, TextP1, CardContainer } from './ProductWsStyle';

interface VersionProps {
  name: string;
  sensor: string[];
  src: string;
}

function ProductWs() {
  const { t } = useTranslation('productWsDB');
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Container>
        <TitleH5>{t('miniTitle')}</TitleH5>
        <TitleH2>{t('title')}</TitleH2>
        <TextP1>{t('text')}</TextP1>
        <CardContainer>

****Error point---------------

          {t<VersionProps[]>('version', { returnObjects: true }).map(item => (
            <MwsCard key={item.name} name={item.name} sensor={item.sensor} src={item.src} />
          ))}

****Error point---------------

        </CardContainer>
      </Container>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

export default ProductWs;
```

### MwsCard.tsx

---

```
import React from 'react';
import * as S from './MwsCardStyle';
import { Version } from './MwsProdDBType';

function MwsCard({ name, sensor, src }: Version) {
  return (
    <S.Container>
      <S.Img src={src} alt={name} />
      <S.Info>
        <S.Title>{name}</S.Title>
        {sensor.map(item => (
          <S.Spec key={item}>{item}</S.Spec>
        ))}
      </S.Info>
    </S.Container>
  );
}

export default MwsCard;
```

### i18n.ts

---

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

const userLanguage = window.navigator.language;

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: localStorage.getItem('language') || userLanguage || 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',

    debug: true,
    keySeparator: '.',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
      wait: true,
      useSuspense: false,
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

### index.js

---

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './i18n';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

reportWebVitals();
```

### app.js

---

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes';
import Theme from './global-styles/Theme';
import './global-styles/import-fonts.css';
import { GlobalStyle } from './global-styles/GlobalStyle';

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>} maxDuration={5000}>
      <Theme>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Routes />
      </Theme>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```